# Getting iframe url changes in website address

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Hey Guys I am a little new to this area.

I have the following code on my site:

```
<body onload="LoadIframeUrlInAddressBar();">

<iframe id="inventorytest" width="100%" height="5000" frameborder="0" src="http://inventorycc.com/apps/inventorysearch/Search/Index/183"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function LoadIframeUrlInAddressBar() {
        var iframe = document.getElementById("inventorytest");
        window.location.hash= iframe.src;
    }
</script>
```

When I access my webpage, and type something into the search within the iframe, the iframe shows at my domain  after a hash.

Example:
http://www.123.com/test-page/#http://inventorycc.com/apps/inventorysearch/Search/Index/183

What I would like to happen is the query strings within my iframe also displays after the hash every time a user does a search or clicks on something with the frame.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Can you please give the link to your website where the problem is or reproduce it at fiddle, it will help us to help you:)

Comment: I have things working on a test page right now:
http://www.huntingtonmazda.com/test-page/

Answer (score 0):

I can really test it on you site but basically the idea is to get the value from the input field from the iframe and implement it in the URL, so to take the value from the iframe when the search button is clicked write (this is the part i cant test but you can add this code after your header)

```
$('iframe[name=select_frame]').contents().find('#btnGo').click(function() {
    var searchquery= $('iframe[name=select_frame]').contents().find('#txtFilter').val();
});
```

then run this js code to change the URL

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/searchquery");
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hey Ram, not sure if you can take a look at the site. I added the code you suggested but what happens when i go to: http://www.huntingtonmazda.com/test-page the URL changes to /searchquery

My thinking was that may be the cause of the javascript but when still doing the search or clicking anything I don't see any updates in the web address. Any ideas what could be wrong?